# NetLogo.Trying to make turtle on a specific patch color die

Tags: netlogo

So I've made the breeds player and zombie:

```
breed [zombies zombie]
breed [players player]
```

I would like to kill a zombie if it walks unto a black patch (pit).

```
to go
  ask zombies
  [
    ;set heading (heading + 45 - (random 90))
    let closest-player min-one-of players[distance myself]
    set heading towards closest-player
    forward 1
    ;if xcor = pcolor black [Death] I have a lot to learn for netlogo syntax
    ;if ycor = pcolor black [Death] these lines are to give an Idea of what I'm trying to do.
  ]
end

to Death  ;; turtle procedure
  set shape "skull"
  set color white
  set heading 0
end
```

Comment: You should edit your question and make a text and code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [*Variables* section of the programming guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#variables):

> a turtle can read and set patch variables of the patch it is standing on.

In your case, this means that your zombies can directly check the `pcolor` of the patch that they're on:

```
if pcolor = black [ Death ]
```

This is the equivalent of the more verbose form using [`patch-here`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here):

```
if [ pcolor ] of patch-here = black [ Death ]
```

You often don't need to use coordinates to identify a patch. NetLogo has plenty of reporters that can help you getting the patch you want. For example: [`patch-ahead`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-ahead), [patch-at](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at), [`patch-at-heading-and-distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at-heading-and-distance), [`patch-here`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here), [`patch-left-and-ahead`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-left-and-ahead) and [`patch-right-and-ahead`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-right-and-ahead).

But in those cases where you do need to find a patch using coordinates, there is [`patch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch):

```
if [ pcolor ] of patch xcor ycor = black [ Death ]
```

But all of this is unnecessary in your case. Stick to the simple `if pcolor = black [ Death ]`.